# Can't format a USB Drive with gibberish text

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount, gparted

Problem started in windows, drive's name printed out gibberish and weird characters, and some files and folders were automatically created with the same gibberish. Formatting through windows and trying different types of fixing guides didn't help, mainly that it was write-protected.

Booted up Ubuntu to try to fix this problem, normal formatting would lead to the error message

```
Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sdb1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sdb1: probing initialization failed: Read-only file system
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Tried using gparted but unmounting the drive causes this error

```
Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.

(gpartedbin:6382): glibmm-CRITICAL **: 
unhandled exception (type Glib::Error) in signal handler:
domain: g_convert_error
code  : 1
what  : Invalid byte sequence in conversion input
```

Tried to change the read-write privileges but didn't seem to work

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

gparted same output and

```
sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1
mkfs.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdb1: Read-only file system

sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb
mkfs.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdb: Read-only file system
```

and chmod doesn't work either

```
find /dev/sdb -type d -execdir chmod 777 -Rv {} +
find /dev/sdb1 -type d -execdir chmod 777 -Rv {} +
```

fdisk -l output

```
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.4 GiB, 7985954816 bytes, 15597568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x462b2602

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        1392 15597567 15596176  7.4G  b W95 FAT32
```

Comment: Is the drive `sdb`?

Answer (score 1):

You've mounted your drive as read-only - chmod won't work since it's a write operation.

You need to remount the drive with read-write permissions:

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw `/dev/sdb1`
```

replace `sdb` with the name of your device.

Comment: just added the fdisk -l output to the question, as for you solution, this is the output
sudo mount -o remount, rw '/dev/sdb1'
mount: /dev/sdb1 not mounted or bad option

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

Comment: @tantan what output?

Comment: sudo mount -o remount, rw '/dev/sdb1' mount: /dev/sdb1 not mounted or bad option In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.